# Upload a dataset to github

Tags: github, dataset

I want to upload a dataset to github (with some related stuff like description files and some links) as done in here http://hfed.github.io/ and in here http://iawe.github.io/

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free
   code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers
   (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics
   on [How to ask a good
   question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards,
   please update your question with the code you have written thus far
   in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Those are websites, hosted by github.  Check this out: https://pages.github.com/

Comment: Are these free?

Comment: Github has various pricing tiers - the student edition is free, and has unlimited private repos! https://github.com/pricing.  If you don't care about anyone seeing your source code, then the free tier has unlimited public repos.

Comment: I basically want to share a collection of data (along with some explanatory readme files and additional informations) publicly so I guess this should work.